# Jquery File Upload blueimp cannot change error message text

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using blueimp's well-known jquery file upload plugin to upload files on my server. I want to change error messages to my own language but I stuck.

Here is just error messages section of my built-in UploadHandler.php file (I couldn't share whole file cause of restrictions so I just copy related section.) located on server/php/UploadHandler.php. I have changed that error texts to my own language but it is not being affected. I read almost all articles about this plugin on stackoverflow and I couldn't find any satisfying solution. Waiting for your helps, Thanks in advance.

```
class UploadHandler
{

    protected $options;

    // PHP File Upload error message codes:
    // http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    protected $error_messages = array(
        1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
        2 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form',
        3 => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded',
        4 => 'No file was uploaded',
        6 => 'Missing a temporary folder',
        7 => 'Failed to write file to disk',
        8 => 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload',
        'post_max_size' => 'The uploaded file exceeds the post_max_size directive in php.ini',
        'max_file_size' => 'File is too big',
        'min_file_size' => 'File is too small',
        'accept_file_types' => 'Filetype not allowed',
        'max_number_of_files' => 'Maximum number of files exceeded',
        'max_width' => 'Image exceeds maximum width',
        'min_width' => 'Image requires a minimum width',
        'max_height' => 'Image exceeds maximum height',
        'min_height' => 'Image requires a minimum height',
        'abort' => 'File upload aborted',
        'image_resize' => 'Failed to resize image'
    );

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Here is my main.js file located on js/main.js

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'server/php/'
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
            // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
            // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            maxFileSize: 999000,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
        });
        // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
        if ($.support.cors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                type: 'HEAD'
            }).fail(function () {
                $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                    .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                    .appendTo('#fileupload');
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0]
        }).always(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help someone.

Find the jquery.fileupload-validade.js inside jquery_upload/js

Search for "// Error and info messages:" (around line 71).

Change the messages manually.